# Locally add the remote to the GitHub original (forked from) repository

Tags: git, github, git-remote

Let's say I have a GitHub fork (`https://github.com/sitaktif/foo`) of an existing repository (`https://github.com/someguy/foo`).

I have a local git repository which has only one git *remote* (`origin`), pointing to my GitHub fork:

```
# Output from `git remote -v`
origin  git@github.com:sitaktif/foo (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:sitaktif/foo (push)
```

I would like to add the *parent* repository to my remotes (i.e. the repository I forked from initially on GitHub), so that it eventually looks like this:

```
# Output from `git remote -v`
origin  git@github.com:sitaktif/foo (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:sitaktif/foo (push)
upstream    https://github.com/someguy/foo (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/someguy/foo (push)
```

I know I can add the remote manually but what I want is to do this automatically (so that I don't have to manually find the address of the parent/original repo for each of my local repositories).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far is to use the GitHub API in a script.

I have created one and made it available there: https://github.com/sitaktif/github-utils/blob/master/github_add_upstream.py

I included minimal documentation in case anybody is interested. Feel free to suggest improvements to the scripts. The code is far from being perfect, so pull requests are welcome.